# How to read updated cloth particles positions

Tags: physx

Currently, I'm reading the Krishna Kumar's book "Learning Physics Modeling with PhysX".

Source code for the cloth example uses a method `getRenderBuffer()` to get points, triangles and quads that we define for the mesh description but he doesn't explain anything about this method on his book.

What does `getRenderBuffer()` actually do? Is this the (only) way to get updated cloth particles positions? If so, since `getRenderBuffer()` is a PxScene object's method, what should we do when we have lots of cloth actors in the scene?

Comment: Added a bit of formatting and created paragraphs to make it easier to read